# Как убирать прелоадер после загрузки первого блока на странице

Tags: javascript

Такая ситуация, есть лендинг, на котором прелоадер стоит до полной загрузки страницы, но так как картинок много и всего много, то страница грузится долго. Можно ли как-то сделать, чтобы прелоадер скрывался при загрузке первых блоков на сайте, например 3, а пока пользователь будет просматривать их, то остальные уже подгрузятся

Comment: *"пока пользователь будет просматривать их, то остальные уже подгрузятся"* --- почему ты так решил? Скорость инета у всех разная, средства просмотра разные,  гаджеты разные. У тебя может и быстро загрузятся, у других будут ещё минуту грузится

Comment: Главное, чтобы верхние уже были прогружены,  и при этом прелоадер скрылся

Comment: Так вот представь, если будет ещё минуту грузится, то прелоадер сколько будет стоять, надо пользователю уже дать возможность хоть с чем-то взаимодействовать, а иначе у него терпение лопнет и он уйдёт

Comment: Так тебе надо копать не в сторону лоадера, а в сторону почему у тебя всё такое тормозное и оптимизировать это. Возможно постепенную подгрузку фото или ещё чего.... а в итоге ты костыли ищешь... потому что у тебя (точнее у пользователя) даже первве блоки могут грузится долго и пользователь всё равно уйдёт.. ...А если первый блок прогрузился, а другие долго грузится будут продолжать - то взаимодействовать будет не с чем и пользователь опять же уйдёт...